# Regex to match positive and negative numbers and text between "" after a character

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for an input that contains positive and negative numbers and sometimes a string between `"` and `"`. I'm not sure if this can be done in only one pattern. Here's some test cases for the pattern:

```
*PATH "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Media\SoundBanks\Ambient\WAV_Data\AD_SMP_SFX_WIND0.wav"
*NODECOLOR 0 255 140
*FILEREF -7
*FREQUENCY 22050
```

The idea would be to use a pattern that returns:

> `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Media\SoundBanks\Ambient\WAV_Data\AD_SMP_SFX_WIND0.wav`
>
> `0 255 140`
>
> `-7`
>
> `22050`

The content always goes after the character *. I've split this in two patterns because I don't know how to do it all in one, but doesn't work:

```
MatchCollection NumberMtaches = Regex.Matches(FileLine, @"(?<=[*])-?[0-9]+");
MatchCollection FilePathMatches = Regex.Matches(FileLine, @"/,([^,]*)(?=,)/g");
```

Comment: Is the format always `*SOMETHING <data>`, where `<data>` may be contained in quotes? If so, why not parse it on that basis?

Comment: Use regex `^\*\w+["\s]+([^"\n]+)` and grab capture group #1

Comment: Yes, the format is always this, yes is a good idea, the problem is that I don't have too much experience with regular expressions.

Comment: Something like [`^\*[A-Z]+ (?:([-\d ]+)|"(.*)")$`](https://regex101.com/r/UXBn1j/1) perhaps? That looks for numbers (but doesn't care too much about the format, e.g. it allows `-` anywhere), or for stuff in quotes

Comment: Neither of your two patterns do anything meaningful here. BTW, you should use string patterns, not regex literals, to define regex in C#.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry, I didn't know this, I've just done it!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read the file into a string and run the following regex:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(filecontents, @"(?m)^\*\w+[\s-[\r\n]]*""?(.*?)""?\r?$")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5C*%5Cw%2B%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%5D*%22%3F%28.*%3F%29%22%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=*PATH%20%22C%3A%5CUsers%5CUser%5CDesktop%5CMedia%5CSoundBanks%5CAmbient%5CWAV_Data%5CAD_SMP_SFX_WIND0.wav%22%0D%0A*NODECOLOR%200%20255%20140%0D%0A*FILEREF%20-7%0D%0A*FREQUENCY%2022050).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - `RegexOptions.Multiline` option on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `\w+`  - one or more word chars
- `[\s-[\r\n]]*` - zero or more whitespaces other than CR and LF
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than an LF char, as few as possible
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `\r?` - an optional CR
- `$` - end of  a line/string.

Comment: I've been trying, but I'm having problems with the `"` characters when putting the pattern in a string variable, how can I fix it?

Comment: @jms2505 Sorry, copy/paste issue on my side, you need to double them.